# Reaching the instance right after the call to startService

Tags: android, android-service

I have the following code:

```
Class A extends Service{
   static instance = null;
   onCreate(){
      instance = this;
   }

   public static createInstance(Context context){
      if(instance==null)
         context.startService(new Intent(context, A.class));
      return instance;
   }
```

After the first call to `createInstance`, it always returns null. I call it from the constructor of the main activity.
How can I make the constructor reach the instance from the very first call?

Comment: why want to start Service this way?

Comment: In case you mean the startService - this is the only way I've known so far.

Comment: @ Vitali Pom : just use `startService(new Intent(context, A.class));` to start service instead of calling `createInstance` method

Comment: Why shall it matter? If there's a good reason, I'll redesign my class hierarchy, but currently it's a very simplified version of what I have and except for the mentioned problem it does all I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into consideration the concept of `Services` in `Android`, I'm sure the implementation of `startService()` involves asynchronous operations. So, by the time `startService()` returns the `onCreate()` method may not even be called by the system. That's why `createInstance()` always returns `null`.

Instead of the the singleton pattern I highly recommend to use `Services` as per the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Answer (score 0):

The right way to start a service is using an intent. In your main activity, create an intent and call `this.startService` with that intent.

You probably shouldn't keep a static instance of anything, let alone of a service. Singleton is a pattern to be wary of in Android, because your application context gets killed and recreated by the OS, so there's no way to know whether the static field is still alive or not.

Comment: I didn't dive into all the details of my implementations. It's another static variable that I initiate at onCreate and it's not initiated at the shown point. Regarding your offer, I do create an intent: new Intent(context, A.class) (see the call to startService). Does it matter where do I create it from?

Comment: Yes, you should create if from the activity and not rely on the singleton pattern.

Comment: So in a dirty implementation - if I receive my Intent from the main Activity and use it here, it shall work?

Comment: No, that's not the point. The point is: don't keep a static instance.